# Capybara / Poltergeist / Devise @current_user is nil - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I got a feature spec which receives a token from an external site and redirects back to my app. Upon redirecting, the client is served an `orders#new` view, which calls `@current_user.items`. This call works in all environments except test. Capybara / Poltergeist or Selenium get `undefined method items for nil class`

I've tried:

- assigning `@current_user` in `before(:each)`
- changing the web driver
- setting `@current_user` to `User.first` for `Rails.env.test?`in my
  controller

How can I make sure `@current_user` works in test?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either login in your feature spec, or use wardens test mode through devise to fake the login - see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara -  so that the current user is set (along with the relevant session cookies).  Feature tests and the app each run separately when using any Capybara driver other than rack-test so attempting to set @current_user in a before(:each) isn't going to work.  Setting it in the controller would probably work for that controller action but won't set the session cookies if you're following links, etc - and doing something like that in a controller just for testing is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Tom's answer made me realize that cookies are not stored because Capybara hosts are not static. I ended up explicitly setting the `server_port`, `server_host` and `app_host` in the `rails_helper` which worked like a charm:

```
Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
Capybara.server_host = 'localhost'
Capybara.server_port = '3000'
```

My app is not using Devise and Warden. Otherwise, Tom's answer would've worked.

Comment: If your app isn't using devise you should remove the devise tag from the question